# Ubuntu doesn't support the necessary drivers for my adapter. What should I do?

Tags: drivers, display, monitor

I am trying to connect two monitors to my laptop which is running Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 as dual boot.

I plugged the first monitor to the HDMI port and the second to the usb 3.0 port via a usb to hdmi adapter. In windows 10, it works perfectly fine and I was able to install/update the necessary drivers. But with Ubuntu, the monitor is not working and no drivers are shown in the Software & Updates apps.

I figured my usb to hdmi adapter doesn't support linux. Then how can someone connect two monitors to their laptop running linux, if their laptop has only one hdmi port?

Here is the link to the adapter I am using
https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/insignia-usb-to-4k-hdmi-adapter-only-at-best-buy/14773591

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 19ff:560d Dynex Insignia USB3.0 Display Adapter Station
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:8001 Microdia Wired Keyboard/Mouse Combo
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 25a7:fa23 Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132926/discussion-on-question-by-filzzo-ubuntu-doesnt-support-the-necessary-drivers-fo).